# Meteor get ObjectId from Blaze template component to .js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have created a dynamic table of which the row values may change per Session.
In last column I present a 5 star rating scale so that the users rates each displayed row, I get the value correctly and in addition I need to know which Id/row the user has rated (since these change dynamically). The html looks like below where  product=this (indicating the row that is rated) is passed in starsRating component:

```
<td class="featuretablerow">
   <p>{{> starsRating mutable=true size='md' class='js-rate-image'
          id='js-rate-image' product=this }}</p>
</td>
```

and the corresponding .js block

```
var starId = $('#js-rate-image').attr('product');
```

I get undefined though when running it, how can I get it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then your intention is to use that jQuery code in the event of a rating. If that is so, then I would argue you are going about that the wrong way. Blaze has proper support for [handling events in templates](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-events).

Something like this should work:

```js
Template.starsRating.events({
  'click': function() {
    console.log('rated product is', this.product);
  }
});
```

In these event handlers, `this` is the current data context of the template.

Answer (score 0):

You just no need to pass anything to get data at events in js file.
HTML file

```
{{#with product}}
    <td class="featuretablerow">
        <p>{{> starsRating mutable=true size='md' class='js-rate-image'
             id='js-rate-image'}}</p>
    </td>
{{/with}}
```

JS file

```
Template.starsRating.events({
    'click': function() {
        console.log('rated product is', this.name);
    }
});
```

You can directly get property